# Compile Error: This apex class is referenced elsewhere in salesforce.com. Remove the usage and try again. at line 0 column 0

Tags: apex

I am getting this error when I try to save my class

**Error: Compile Error: This apex class is referenced elsewhere in salesforce.com. Remove the usage and try again. at line 0 column 0**

Any idea what this means or how to clear it?

I was writing code using force IDE and for some reason it was not saving the changes I was making to the class. I tried copying the code from the IDE and paste it to class from the browser and I got this error.

I tried closing the IDE and tried using the browser and still got the error.

Thanks

Comment: Were you trying to change the classname ?

Comment: No ... As usual was updating the class from IDE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were most likely changing the class name or the name of something that was needed(referenced) in that VF page therefore, breaking the functionality of this class for the VF page.

Comment: Ah!! i get it... i did change the class name of the wrapper class in the class

Answer (score 3):

Found a workaround

Remove the reference to the class from the Vf pages. Save the Vf page.

Save the class and it saves now. go back to the Vf pages and add reference back to the class. Things should be normal again till you hit the same error again.

Not sure if its a bug or something i did wrong.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more -- it's the second time I've had to use this technique in order to save my controller class.

Comment: Glad this was help to you